# Como trocar um charset de uma tabela para utf8 em um banco de dados latin1?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Estou tentando trocar o charset de uma tabela para utf8 em um BD que contém todas as outras tabelas como latin1swedish. Eu executei vários comandos e diz que trocou, mostra que aquela tabela é a unica como utf8, mas qualquer inserção continua dando erros.

Por exemplo, eu insiro no campo `endereco` da tabela `coordenadas_cache`, algo como: `São Sebastião`

Quando vou olhar no phpMyAdmin, está: `SÃ£o SebastiÃ£o`

O que posso fazer?

Comment: Já tentou fazer uma regex para correçao?

Comment: Não, não sei o que é isso. Como seria isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem, eu consegui resolver. Como eu utilizo `mysqli_connect()` para conectar ao BD, eu por acaso descobri que tem um comando que seta o charset (para o envio, suponho) da query de inserção. O comando é o `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")`, sendo `$mysqli` a variável utilizada para conectar-se ao banco de dados no comando `$mysqli = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd")`